# using fetch method to get data from express endpoint shows error React Redux

Tags: node.js, express, fetch, redux

I am using redux in my application. when the app mounts i am trying to get all the items from using the action

```
export default function getItems(){
return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(getJobsRequest());
    return fetch('http://localhost:5000/items', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authentication': localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
    }).then(function(response){
        console.log(response)
        return response.json()
    }).then(function(response){
        console.log(response)
        dispatch(getJobsSuccess())
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log('error')
    })  
}
```

}

But something weird happens in between and I can see response object in the console. but it doesn't reach the express end point

```
`router.get('/items',function(req,res){
    console.log('im called')

})`
```

Comment: "something weird happens". Can you be more specific? What does your response object look like? And which of the console logs shows that response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure this out. There was a problem with the fallback handling as it is single page app.

It was serving the get requests with public file index.html so I had to handle it like following:

```
app.get('*', function(req,res){
if(req.accept('html')){res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,''public))}
  next() })
```